# How to get the names of the json columns from firebase? I leave an example below my question

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I would like to list the names of the dates, such as 24_1_2020, 25_1_2020, etc ...

Comment: You should provide some code that you already tried. Do you want to read the label of the date?

Comment: the parent of the data i need get the keys

Comment: That sounds feasible if you use the [Firebase API for Android app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start). If you've tried this already but ran into problems, please edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, as it's quite useful).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `teLm ... IWV2` is the `uid` of the authenticated user, to display only those keys `24_1_2020`, `25_1_2020`, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Mensaje").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();
            Log.d(TAG, key);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

See, I have used the `getChildren()` method to loop through the `DataSnapshot` object, which basically contains all children under the `uid` node. Calling `getKey()`, you can get each key that is corresponding to each child.

If `teLm ... IWV2` is not the `uid` of the authenticated user, then simply add that String directly in your reference:

```
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Mensaje").child("teLm ... IWV2");
```